# Стоит ли ставить запятую в обороте «не дольше чем»?

Tags: пунктуация

Стоит ли ставить запятую в обороте «не дольше чем»?

*... обеспечить работу круглосуточной аварийно-диспетчерской службы, в которую можно будет дозвониться не дольше чем за 5 минут.*

Comment: Слово "дольше" не нравится. "Дозвониться не дольше чем..." – так не говорят.

Comment: может так: «...с которой можно связаться не более чем за 5 минут»?

Comment: Может, и так...

Comment: "Не дольше чем на неделю" ― это было её желание. [Юрий Трифонов. Обмен (1969)]  "... война эта продлится не дольше чем до ближайшего дождя,  [Владимир Войнович]

Comment: Остаться не дольше чем на неделю. Продлится не дольше чем до ближайшего дождя. И дозвониться не дольше чем за пять минут. Вы разницы не чувствуете? Плохо.

Answer (score 3):

Запятая не ставится.

Розенталь: [§ 41. Цельные по смыслу выражения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146)

Внутри сочетаний (не) больше чем, (не) меньше чем, (не) раньше чем, (не) позже чем и т. п., **если они не содержат сравнения, запятая не ставится**: Посылка весит не больше чем восемь килограммов.

Answer (score 1):

Если речь о запятой, то она не нужна. Объяснение дано в ответе @Sibylla.

Но нужно заметить, что оборот "не дольше чем" не сочетается с глаголом совершенного вида "дозвониться". У глагола сов. вида нет длительности. Можно делать (несов. вид) что-то "(не) дольше чем" , но нельзя сделать (сов. вид) что-то "(не) дольше чем".

Корректно:

Звонить долго - звонить дольше - звонить не дольше чем пять минут

Неверно:

Дозвониться долго - дозвониться дольше - дозвониться дольше чем за 5 минут

Корректно:

Дозвониться за 5 минут - дозвониться за **более** чем 5 минут - дозвониться не  **более** чем за 5 минут.